# puppeteer: how do I take a screenshot of a PDF in headless mode?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, screenshot

I am unable to take screenshot of the PDF in headless mode.

**Note: I am relatively new to exploring puppeteer.**

### Approach 1:

I served a PDF from the Node JS server, and using puppeteer I navigated to that endpoint (http://localhost:5000/abc.pdf), it opens up the pdf viewer and was able to take the screenshot of it but in { headless : false } mode

I want to address two issues-

1. As the app will be deployed on the server, take a screenshot in { headless : true } mode. In headless mode it gives below error - `net::ERR_ABORTED at http://localhost:5000/file.pdf`. Assuming puppeteer doesn't have the  ability to scrape a PDF.
2. Take the screenshot of the specific element which displays the actual pdf page. My guess is that, this is not getting accomplished because I am taking the screenshot in { headless  : false } mode.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function pdf2Img(pdfPath) {
  try {
    // (issue 1) giving error on setting { headless: true }  
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      // args: [
      //   '--disable-web-security',
      //   '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins',
      //   '--disable-site-isolation-trials',
      // ],
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Set the viewport's width and height
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1150 });
  

    await page.goto(pdfPath, {
      waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded', 'load'],
      timeout: 30000,
    });

    // sleep 
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 3000));

    await page.waitForSelector('embed');

    // Access the embed tag using page.$()
    const embedTag = await page.$('embed');
    console.log({ embedTag });
    
    // const { x, y, width, height } = await embedTag.boundingBox();
    // console.log({ x, y, width, height }); // { x: 0, y: 0, width: 1920, height: 1150 }

    // Get the src attribute of the embed tag
    // const src = await page.evaluate(
    //   (node) => node.getAttribute('src'),
    //   embedTag
    // );
    // console.log(src);
    
    await embedTag.screenshot({
      path: `file.jpeg`,
      type: 'jpeg',
      quality: 100,
      
      // (issue 2) clipping because element-specific screenshot isn't working even in headful mode...
      clip: {
        x: 700,
        y: 60,
        width: 800,
        height: 1100,
      },
    });

    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
})('http://localhost:5000/file.pdf')
```

### Approach 2:

Note, I also tried a different solution where I set content as HTML and then try to take the screenshot. Unfortunately this isn't working too.

> *Same two issues as Approach 1*

Handlebars template-

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <title> pdf2Img </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='wrapper'>

      {{!-- <object
        id='pdfDoc'
        width='100%'
        height='100%'
        data={{pdfDataUrl}}
        type='application/pdf'
      /> --}}

      <iframe
        id='pdfDoc'
        width='100%'
        height='100%'
        src={{pdfDataUrl}}
        type='application/pdf'
      />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const hbs = require('handlebars');

function blobToBase64(blob) {
  return fs.readFileSync(blob, 'base64');
}
const readHtmlFromTemplate = function (templateFolder, templateName) {
  const FILE_PATH = path.join(
    process.cwd(),
    templateFolder,
    `${templateName}.hbs`
  );
  const html = fs.readFileSync(FILE_PATH, 'utf-8');
  return html;
};

const bindDataWithHtml = (html, data) => {
  return hbs.compile(html)(data);
};

const base64String = blobToBase64('./file.pdf');

(async function pdf2Img() {
  try {
     // (issue 1) Unlike first approach, this time it is not giving error on setting { headless: true } but the screenshot is blank...
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Set the viewport's width and height
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1150 });

    // html template using handlebars and data binding
    const html = readHtmlFromTemplate('invoice-template', 'pdf');
    const htmlContent = bindDataWithHtml(html, {
      pdfDataUrl: `data:application/pdf;base64,${base64String}`,
    });

    /* tried without HBS
    const htmlContent = `
      <div id="pdfDoc">
      <object id="pdf"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        src="data:application/pdf;base64,${base64String}"
        type="application/pdf" class="internal"
        title="pdf doc"
        />
    </div>`;
    */

    await page.setContent(htmlContent, {
      waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded', 'load'],
      timeout: 10_000,
    });

    await page.waitForSelector('#pdfDoc', { timeout: 10_000, visible: true });
    const pdfDoc = await page.$('#pdfDoc');
    console.log({ pdfDoc });

    // sleep 
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

     // (issue 2) element-specific screenshot isn't working even in headful mode...
    const s = await pdfDoc.screenshot({
      path: 'file.jpeg',
      type: 'jpeg',
      quality: 100,
    });

    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
})();
```

Please advise.

Comment: specify what you mean by "cannot" so we do not need to guess.

Comment: Which part you are referring to?

Comment: What do you need the screenshot for? You'd be essentially testing that Chromium can display PDFs, are you sure that's the goal?

Comment: To be precise, the requirement is to take the screenshot of the PDF in JPEG format and convert it to base64 string to send it to downstream system. In short the goal is to convert PDF Doc to an image.

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do but I don't have time to work out a full example yet. Your code is rather complex, so I suggest stripping it down a bit. Anyway, `<embed>` is inside a shadow root, so you might try using `const embedTag = await page.waitForSelector('>>> embed');` to pierce the shadow root. That said, I agree that this may be an xy problem--just use an off-the-shelf package if at all possible.